# Screen resolution test

Tags: testing, screen, resolution

Does anyone know a desktop app for testing websites in different screen resolutions?  The reason I am looking for a desktop app is because I want to be able to test websites that have internal URLs [of course I want to test in resolutions that are not available on my computer).

Thanks

Comment: You can use VirtualBox to do this. You can run a virtual machine, change the resolution and last take a screen shot (rinse and repeat for other resolutions).

Comment: You don't say what platform you want this app on. Also, I'm not sure how an app can "test" resolutions you don't have. I'm pretty sure that what people normally do is just resize the window. (This assumes you have a screen at least as large as the largest resolution you care about testing.) You could use an extension like https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/window-resizer/kkelicaakdanhinjdeammmilcgefonfh to help you out with that.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem. You can write `JUnit` and `Selenium` test app for that. It's not big deal, simply change screen resolution of driver object and take print screen automaticly. Image files are store in your project so you can see after test all resolutions of your site. Here is code for that :

```
public class TestCase1 {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private WebDriver driver;

    private String url;

    public TestCase1() {
    }

    @BeforeClass
    public static void setUpClass() {
    }

    @AfterClass
    public static void tearDownClass() {
    }

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        // array of test urls
        this.url = "http://www.google.com/";

        // ChromeDriver
        //System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", PATH_TO_CHROMEDRIVER);
        //driver = new ChromeDriver();

        driver = new FirefoxDriver();

        driver.get(this.url);
    }

    @After
    public void tearDown() {
        driver.quit();
    }

    @Test
    public void testResolution() {
        driver.navigate().to(this.url);

        String[] resulutions = {
            "1366x768",
            "1920x1080"
            // add resolution
        };

        for (String resulution : resulutions) {
            String[] parts = resulution.split("x");

            // Screen resolution
            Dimension screenRes = new Dimension(Integer.parseInt(parts[0]),Integer.parseInt(parts[1]));

            // Set browser resolution
            driver.manage().window().setSize(screenRes);

            // little pause
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                //Logger.getLogger(TestClass.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }

            driver.navigate().refresh();

            // little pause
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                //Logger.getLogger(TestClass.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }

            this.takeScreenShot(resulution);
        }

    }

    /**
     * 
     * @param fileName 
     */
    private void takeScreenShot(String fileName) {
        File screenShot = ((TakesScreenshot) driver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);
        try {
            FileUtils.copyFile(screenShot, new File(fileName + ".png"));
        } catch (IOException ioe) {
            throw new RuntimeException(ioe.getMessage(), ioe);
        }
    }

}
```

Here is [link](http://nikolaloncar.com/testing-web-app-or-site-automatically-on-different-screen-resolutions/) for setting test project, importing selenium and other staff that you need to do that.